# Button click page refresh

Tags: html, css

I have a project with a master page and one web form page. I create menu on left hand side and on center I create button and search bar.. currently I am done with only html and css..no coding is begin

When I open page then when I click on button then whole page refreshes and when page refreshesm, the menu also refreshes and looks weird .. how to stop the whole page refresh?

html and css

```
    body 
{
     font-family:Calibri;

}
.lefttabs    {
    background-color:#1E1E1E;
    color:White;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:medium;

    width: 300px; 
    height: 850px;
    z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
    padding-top: 60px; 
    /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}
.lefttabs a {


    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size:medium;
    color:White;
    width: 133px;
    margin-left: 0px;


  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;

  line-height: 24px;  


}
.lefttabs ul
{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;

    padding: 0;




 }
.lefttabs li
{
    list-style:none;



 }
 .lefttabs li  a 
{
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
   padding: 10px 0px 30px 10px;
  /*padding-left: 10px;*/
  /*padding-top: 10px;*/
  width: 96%;
  /*add this*/


 } 
.lefttabs a:hover
{

 background-color:White;
color:Black;
 }
 .imga
{
   display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;

    margin-right: 20px;

}
.lefttabs a imga{
  margin:0 8px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;  /* needed */
}

 @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.rightdiv
{
    width: 900px;

    background-color:White;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 320px;
    }


.BTN
{
    color:White;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background-color: #008CBA;
    border:none;

    }

.search 
{
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding:8px 15px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);

    border:0px solid #dbdbdb;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    width: 50%;

}  

.button {
                position:relative;
                padding:6px 15px;
                left:-8px;
                border:2px solid #207cca;
                background-color:#207cca;
                color:#fafafa;
}
.button:hover  {
                background-color:#fafafa;
                color:#207cca;
}

    <body background="images/bggcol.jpg">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <div class="lefttabs">
    <ul >
    <li>
    <a href=""><img class="imga" alt="a1" src="images/eve.bmp" border="0" />a1</a>

    </li>
    <li>
    <a href=""> <img class="imga" alt="a2" src="images/eve.bmp" border="0" />a2</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
    <a href=""> <img class="imga" alt="a3" src="images/ve.bmp" border="0" />a3</a>
    </li>
   <li> 
    <a href=""><img class="imga" alt="a4" src="images/nfc.bmp" border="0" />a4</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
    <a href=""><img class="imga" alt="a5" src="images/user.bmp"  border="0" />a5</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
    <a href=""><img class="imga" alt="a6" src="images/rol.bmp" border="0" />a6</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
    <a href=""><img class="imga" alt="a7" src="images/rep.bmp" border="0" />a7</a>
    </li>
     <li> 
     <a href=""><img class="imga" alt="a8" src="images/lo.bmp" border="0" />a8</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>



    </form>
</body>
```

web form

```
    <div class="rightdiv">

<input type="text"  class="search"  placeholder="Search..." />
 <input type="button" class="button"  value="Search"/>

<hr />


    <asp:Button  CssClass="BTN" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="OVERVIEW" />

    <asp:Button   CssClass="BTN" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="ADD DRIVER" />
    <asp:Button  CssClass="BTN" ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="ADD DEVICE" />
    <asp:Button  CssClass="BTN" ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="ADD TAG" />
    </div>
```

Comment: You try adding <a href="#"> # as href for each button link and let me know.

Comment: This is not refresh, this is post request to your form. For cancel request, add handler to button-click and refturn false, but you accept data only throw the post-request.

Comment: You can also use jquery function for that page with event.preventDefault();

Comment: now i remove href . and still page send request

Answer (score 0):

A button in HTML is default a form submit button. If you add some javascript to the onclick event of the button: onclick="javascript:return false;" it will not send the form.

If it is meant to be submitted as i would expect with a search bar, it will refresh because you are sending a message to a server and the reply triggers a page refresh to display results.